# Craft 3 -get user id and username

Tags: authentication, twig

I'm using **craft 3 Pro** to make a website where users have a private area.
Users register and when login happens they are redirected to a page in the private area with respective info about that user.

When i use `{% requireLogin %}` with `{{ currentUser.id }}` craft 3 outputs the ID of the user that has active login in the CP (control panel).

But what i need is the ID of the user that made login in the frontend to access private area and not user ID that is logged in CP.

I'm reading craft 3 docs but didn't find the answer i'm looking for.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Craft does not make difference between CP and SITE users. There are only permissions to allow for a user to access the Control Panel.

However you can acces the basic user object with

`craft.app.user` That means the logged in user id is `craft.app.user.id`

If you want to access the User element to get the values of the custom fields you assigned to the users then

`craft.app.user.identity` and `craft.app.user.identity.yourCustomField`

---

#### What you need is to differentiate Admins from Regular users:

```
{% set userGroups = craft.app.user.identity.getGroups() %}
```

If `userGroups` contains the `Admin` user group, your user...is an admin clearly

---

Also there is a bunch of methods and properties for the identity object here:
https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-elements-user.html#public-properties

Dig in!